# angular - rxjs Observable array

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I'm trying to have an array of categories that contains item but without no luck.
This is the code:

```
public getItemsAndSubcategoriesFromCatAndCategory(catalogue_key: string, category_key: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.categoriesService.getSubCategories(catalogue_key, category_key)
            .combineAll()
            .switchMap((val) => {
                const obj = {};
                this.getItemsInSubcategory(catalogue_key, val[0].key).map((items) => {
                    obj[val[0].key] = items;
                });
                return obj;
            });
    }
```

the error is:

> Argument of type (val: {}) => {} is not assignable to parameter of
>   type (value: {}, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>

any Idea?

Comment: can you add how does your data looks like, result of `getSubCategories` and `getItemsInSubcategory` ?

Answer (score 0):

`.switchMap` needs `Observable` to be returned instead of `{}`.

So use

```
return Observable.of(obj)
```

instead of

```
return obj
```

EDIT:

You can write in more declarative syntax:

```
.switchMap(([firstValue]) => Observable.of(
  this.getItemsInSubcategory(catalogue_key, firstValue.key)
    .reduce((obj, items) => Object.assign({}, obj, {
      [firstValue.key]: items
    }, {})
))
```